# Ionic - build differences

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm building project (android .apk files) on two different machines.

As long as i am updating aplication (on smartphone) from apk made on same machine as installed version it is ok. When im trying to update by apk file from other machine it fails - installation is not successful.

What may cause the problem?

Both machines has the same ionic, cordova and ionic-app-lib version.

Comment: post the error you are getting. You have given very little information to debug

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/nNkox - thats only error information that i can get due to no access to install error log of android